# PHP Date not sticking

Tags: php, date

I'm having a hard time getting dates to stick in variables. When I when I'm tyring to subtract months from a current date it is giving me 0 back (defaulting back to 1-1-1970).

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

PHP:

```
$progress = 5;
$initialDate = date('m-d-Y');
echo "ini date: " . date('m-01-Y',$initialDate) . "<br>";
$date = date('m-01-Y', strtotime("-$progress months", strtotime(date('m-d-Y',$initialDate))));
echo "date: " . $date . "<br>";
```

output:

```
ini date: 12-01-2014
date: 08-01-1969
```

Comment: That output does not match your code, the second parameter of `date()` should be a timestamp, not a formatted date. You should probably keep your dates as timestamps (or `DateTime` objects...) and only format them when you output them to the browser.

Comment: If you turn PHP error output on, you'll get more of an idea of where the problem is—as @jeroen says, PHP will be expecting a timestamp where you're passing a string with a formatted date in, which will cause a PHP Notice: "A non well formed numeric value encountered..."

Comment: PHP errors are on, and that is exactly my code and output.

Comment: I respectfully suggest that if PHP errors are on, and that's exactly your code and output, then something strange is going on, as you should have seen an error with your code. Check your server error log for the error I mentioned—if you see it there, but didn't see it when you ran your code, then you have a problem with your error reporting settings.

Comment: I'm running E_ALL for error reporting. This issue is resolved with the answer below though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd argument to date() must be in internal Timestamp format, i.e. *"number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)"*.

`strtotime()` is really intended to convert a user input into internal date format. If you want to do math with dates, it is better to use a more precise method. I would suggest reading up on `date_add()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

However, the simplest fix to your code is this:

```
    $progress = 5;
    $initialDate = time();  // current timestamp, including seconds
    echo "initialDate: $initialDate<br>";
    echo "ini date: " . date('m-01-Y',$initialDate) . "<br>";
    $date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime("-$progress months", strtotime(date('Y-01-d',$initialDate))));
    echo "date: " . $date . "<br>";
```

Note that I used Y-01-d format for the date fed to strtotime, to go back to the 1st of the month before doing the date math, for two reasons:

- Y-m-d format has no danger of being interpreted incorrectly by strtotime, unlike m/d/y and d/m/y.
- If you are going back 5 months from Jul 30 to Feb 1, it is safer to have Jul 1 as the intermediate step, not Feb 28. "Safer" meaning you don't even *need* to test if strtotime handles Feb 28 properly.

Comment: This was a great explination and helped me get to where I needed to be. Thanks Tom!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the DateTime object as well. I find it a little more reliable myself. You basically just initiate a DateTime object and then use its ::sub function to subtract a DateInterval in the amount of $progress months.

```
 $progress = 5;
 $initialDate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-01"));
 echo "ini date: ".$initialDate->format("m-01-Y")."<br />";
 $date = $initialDate->sub(new DateInterval("P".$progress."M"));
 echo "date: ".$date->format("m-01-Y")."<br />";
```

Output:

```
 ini date: 12-01-2014
 date: 07-01-2014
```

Comment: For Jul 30 your code returns Mar 1. It should be Feb 1.

Comment: I guess that makes sense since it would be subtracting the 30 days in July before subtracting the next 4 months, so it ends up 1 month off when converting them back to 01. I simply changed it so that when setting the initial date, it forces it to use the first day of the month so the month count isn't affected.